# Trying to reverse a string on Java. Why can't I get the reversed text as my only output?

Tags: java, function

I can't get my function to return the reversed string. I keep getting the original string, plus the reversed sting attached together.

P.S this is obviously a question from someone new. Cut me some slack and save me from the horribly demoralizing down vote.

```
    int i;
    reverse = reverse.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", "").toLowerCase();

    for (i = reverse.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    reverse = reverse + reverse.charAt(i);
    }

    return reverse;
}
```

Comment: What is your input? What is string was tested?

Comment: What do you think `reverse = reverse + ...` does?

Comment: So, you want to delete all non letters from you string and then reverse it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the snippet to,

```
String reverse_string="";
for (i = reverse.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    reverse_string += reverse.charAt(i);
    }
return reverse_string;
```

You will need a separate String variable to contsruct the newly reversed string.

Comment: It does not work properly when `reverse` includes surrogate pairs.

Comment: Thank you Joey, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You need another `String` (or some other method / memory) to build your return value (consider "a", starting from the end of the `String` add "a" - thus you get "aa"). Instead, I would use a `StringBuilder` - and the entire method might be written like

```
return new StringBuilder(reverse.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", "")
        .toLowerCase()).reverse().toString();
```

Comment: Hi Elliot, I tried to look up some of the documentation, but I couldn't really understand why the "+" is there. What would happen if I left that out?

Comment: @JWL1988 It matches one or more consecutive non-letters, since you replace them all anyway it wouldn't really change anything in this specific case. The '+' *specifically* adds "or more". Consider `"a   b"` ("a", 3 spaces and "b"), `"a   b".split("\\s+")` yields a very different result to `"a   b".split("\\s")`

Answer (score 2):

Why not just let the existing Java api do this for you?

```
 String someString = "somestring123";
    System.out.println(new StringBuilder(someString).reverse().toString());
```

output:
[StringBuilder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nLEh.png)

Comment: This is for a CS class and this was the code snippet the professor gave to us to use.